# grab single value from restsharp json response

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need easy way to grab value from this json response by resetsharp. Variable "response2" contains the json like picture attached. I want to grab a single value of "contactId" from that json. I already tried with "Headers" but this says- System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' How can i fix to grab "contactId" value?

[image: pic]

```
var client2 = new RestClient("https://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts?query[email]=test@gmail.com");
var request2 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

request2.AddHeader("X-Auth-Token", "api-key 948dff90-my-key-f3c6");
request2.AddParameter("application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody);

var response2 = client2.Execute(request2);

string contactId = response2.Headers.ToList().Find(x => x.Name == "contactId").Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll receive the response inside the Content property of response2 as a string.
try this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response2.Content);
Console.WriteLine(obj[0].ContactId);
```

Comment: use ?.ContactId, will crash if null

Comment: my bad it should be obj[0].ContactId

Comment: Works! Thanks dude